# Prevent table resizing in PDF

Tags: php, html-table, pdf-generation, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to generate PDF from a form. In form I have an option to adding new rows to table. The problem is when count of rows is too big for generated PDF page. Then the table is resizing (it's smaller) instead of going to the next page.

This is mpdf code:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('UTF-8','A4','','',20,15,48,25,10,10);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(generatePDF());
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

This is html table code:

```
function getHTMLStyle(){

$html ='<table class="items" width="100%" style="font-size: 9pt; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="8">
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">A</td>
                <td width="95%"><b>'.$a.'</b><br /><br /> '.$_POST['title'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >B</td>
                <td ><b>'.$b.'</b><br /><br /> '.$_POST['organizationName'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >C</td>
                <td></td>
                <table class="items2" width="100%" page-break-before="always" >
                    <tr>
                        <td ><b>'.$c.'</b></td>'.addTableC().'
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </tr>
```

This is image with property view:

[image]

And this is an amage with wrong view:

[image]

How can I make a break in table and continue to another side?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're incorrectly nesting tables -

```
         <tr>
            <td >C</td>
            <td></td>
            <table class="items2" width="100%" page-break-before="always" >
                <tr>
                    <td ><b>'.$c.'</b></td>'.addTableC().'
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
```

The table should be inside the `<td>` tag, like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>
    <table class="items2" width="100%" page-break-before="always" >
      <tr>
        <td ><b>'.$c.'</b></td>'.addTableC().'
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's true but it change nothing ;/

Comment: Are you closing your table tag too?

Comment: Yes. I think that mpdf mayby not support nested tables very well. I divide this code to separate tables and then it started works. But its not an elegant solution.

Comment: It does support nested tables, I use it for a timesheet generation system for students and haven't had any similar issues. I seem to recall it can have issues with some CSS styles/classes. Can you try applying styles in HTML4/Inline formats?

Comment: I have also issues with nested tables in mPDF